# I need to convert a text field representing time into a numerical format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On an excel sheet, one of the columns "time duration" is broken down into DAYS HOURS MINUTES. For example:

```
1 day 1 minute
12 hours 10 minutes
5 minutes
2 days 1 hour
```

I am trying to convert these all into hours with a number format. The above would read

```
24.01666667
12.17
0.083333333
49
```

Can this be done within Excel?

Comment: `=SUM(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,"&{"'day'","'hour'","'min'","'sec'"}&")]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")*{24,1,0.01667,0.00278},0))`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yet while this will calculate the days into hours it is not taking into consideration hours and minutes. It will only calculate the days into hours? "1 day 1 hour 1 minute" shows as 24.000 not as 25.01667

Comment: You may need to use Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode to make it an array formula, As per the instructions on the linked duplicate.

Comment: Seems like that would be the case but even with an array formula, the code is not showing the right outcome. For example, '4 days 7 hours 33 minutes' would be  (4*24)+(7*1)+(33*1/60)+(0*1/3600) which is 103.55
Yet your formula, even with dynamic array, gives 100.0667. Perhaps Im missing something

Comment: I get 103.55: https://imgur.com/erQoLaa

Comment: I wonder if I need to change any preferences/features in my excel (2013) for FILTERXML? I don't see a difference in our formulas https://imgur.com/a/iuddV4i

Comment: What is the exact formula you are using, I see you changed to SUMPRODUCT, what else did you change?

Comment: I'm sorry, I chose the incorrect screenshot, this https://imgur.com/wivd8mi is what I'm using. It seems the output is X*(24+1+0.01667+0.00278) which in that example X = 4 for the '4days'

Comment: Use the `Evaluate Function` on the formula bar and step through the function.  It has to be the data.  Maybe you have non breaking spaces instead of normal spaces in the data.

Comment: Data seems clear, nothing out of the ordinary. Im not familiar with FILTERXML but it seems somewhere here it's only reading the 4 and not 7 nor 33 https://imgur.com/a/dAjbTWR shouldn't it say contains 'day' & 'hours' & 'minutes'

Comment: Maybe your version does not allow the array form.  Look at the link which has each part broken out.  That is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the help Scott. I'll have to find a workaround